# Why SonarScanner for Maven skips all projects except the root one

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I downloaded and scanned the Web Goat Vulnerable application directories on my system using SonarQube and I noticed that some of the inner folders were skipped.

Is there any way by which all the folders can be scanned altogether?

Here's a sample of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Could you please paste in the sonar properties you have used to analyze the project. Also, you can try by adding **`sonar.sources=.`** to your sonar properties to scan all the folders.

Comment: sonar.projectKey=webgoat
 sonar.projectName=webgoat
 sonar.projectVersion=1.0
 sonar.sources=.
 sonar.language=java
 sonar.sourceEncoding=UFT-8
 sonar.java.binaries=D:\java\jdk-11.0.11\bin

Comment: Does adding `sonar.sources=.` worked for you ?

Comment: No , it didn't work .

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine. The SonarScanner for Maven is an aggregator plugin. It is executes only on the root project, but it includes data from other projects as should. It is required because SonarScanner have to analyze all files together and next send the analysis result of all the modules in a one push.

Open your SonarQube/SonarCloud instance and check that the whole codebase has been scanned as should.